# Removing parts of a JSON response from API

Tags: json, angularjs, api

I use this API to get currency rates:

```
http://devel.farebookings.com/api/curconversor/GBP/USD/1/
```

The response is:

```
USD 1.5129
```

But all i want is this bit

```
1.5128
```

How would i modify the code below to do that:

```
$http({method: 'GET',
       url: "http://devel.farebookings.com/api/curconversor/GBP/USD/1/"}).

 success(function(status) {

        // your code when success
        localStorage.gbpUSD = status;

    }).
```

status is the response and comes out as

```
 USD 1.5129
```

Comment: so, you're asking how to do basic javascript string manipulation, right?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods_2 you could use slice, split, substr, substring, or replace to accomplish your goals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring):

```
$http({method: 'GET',
   url: "http://devel.farebookings.com/api/curconversor/GBP/USD/1/"}).

   success(function(status) {
    // your code when success
    localStorage.gbpUSD = status.substring(4);
}).
```

Comment: Thats perfect, Thank you :)

Comment: Hi @CarlR if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.